# Infragistics grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

I am using Infragistics `WebDataGrid` to display data.
When one of the column have `null` value, that row do not displayed in that grid.

Have anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Nullable` property of the required column to `Nullable.Null` as shown below:

```
// Get a column.
UltraGridColumn column = this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Phone"];

// Set the Nullable to Null so the UltraGrid
column.Nullable = Nullable.Null;
```